# Переход с boost signal к boost signal 2

Tags: c++, bash, boost

Я собираюсь использовать `boost::signal` для того, чтобы после принудительного завершения программы (ctrl+с) сохранялись данные в БД,закрывались сокеты и т.п.

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::signal_set> pSignalQuit;
int main()
{
    ...
    pSignalQuit->add(SIGQUIT);
    pSignalQuit->async_wait(boost::bind(&CKernel::HandleStop, this));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Boost рекомендует перейти на  `boost::signal2`, так как старая версия уже не поддерживается и вроде бы менее безопасная. Но в ней я не нашел похожего интерфейса. Вообще стоит ли переходить для моего случая?

Comment: Причем тут `boost::signal`, если вы используете `boost::asio`? И зачем вообще использовать  кроссплатформанную библиотеку для обработки платформозависимых сигналов?

Comment: @Ariox `boost::signal` использую для того, чтобы при завершений программы (ctr+c) вызвать функцию `HandleStop`. А как мне реализовать кроссплатформенно? Мне нужно как-то подать сигнал программе о сохранении данных в БД и закрытии сокетов.  Например, я видал пример где в цикле считывали нажатие с помощью функции `kbhit()`, но она только под `windows`. Может создать отдельно поток и в нём считывать командную строку?

Comment: `boost::asio::signal_set` - это не часть `boost::signal`, `boost::signal` и `boost::signal2` никак не связаны с сигналами операционной системы, они реализуют собственный механизм сигналов. Тот способ, который вы используете - вполне рабочий, и будет работать до тех пор, пока его поддерживает `boost::asio`, а там он [не помечен как устаревший](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html). И он действительно работает не только под linux, но и под windows, о чем я раньше не знал.